# mouseover navigation if dropped down

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I currently have the following script:

http://jsfiddle.net/oshirowanen/mnXdv/

Which works fine, i.e. if a click on one of the navigations, it drops down, if the click on another, the existing dropdown disappears and the other dropdown appears, if i click anywhere on the document, whichever navigation is opened, will disappear.

How can I add a mouseover, so the other navigation automatically drops down, if another navigation is already dropped down.  However, if no navigation is dropped down, to cause a dropdown, it must be clicked for it to dropdown, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/mnXdv/8/

Although I would favour using `<ul>`'s with CSS styles to control the `.active` state, so the Javascript would become much simpler, something like:

```
function makeActive(el) {
    $('.menu .active').removeClass('active');
    $(el).parent().addClass('active');
}

$('.menu li a').click(function() {
    makeActive(this);
});

$('.menu li a').hover(function() {
    if ($('.menu .active').length == 0) {
        return;
    }
    makeActive(this);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to use [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

```
$('.navigation').click(function(event) {
    $(this).siblings('.navigation.active').click();
    $(this).toggleClass('active').next().toggle();
    event.stopPropagation();
}).hover(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.navigation.active').click();
    $(this).toggleClass('active').next().toggle();
}, function() {});
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/mnXdv/6/).

Comment: Almost, however the hover should not work if no dropdown is dropped, to activate the hover, a dropdown must already be dropped, once all dropdowns are closed, the hover should not work.